# Could not find org.koin:koin-test:2.0.1

Tags: android, koin

I have recently removed jcenter() repository from the project-level build Gradle.

Since then Koin (version: 2.2.2) started giving me the compile-time error below:

Could not find org.koin:koin-test:2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

you should add **mavenCentral()** instead of **jcenter()** recording to Koin [documentation](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin#maven-central) make sure Koin version is `koin_version= "3.2.2"`, and in the build.gradle use this implementation: `implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.2.2"`

Answer (score 0):

koin-test 2.0.x was released years ago on Jcenter. You need to upgrade to latest version as possible.

Answer (score 0):

the error gone when i downgrade to Jcenter and use org.koin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

replace mavenCentral() with jcenter() and add the koin library version 2.0.1. It will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).